# How should one react to being wronged by someone that is heedless and takes advantage of Allah's mercy?

Tags: forgiveness, muslim-practices

Salam, I have a personal question.

I was severely wronged by someone.  He's also Muslim, all is okay now and I believe he's asked for forgiveness. How does this go about in terms of being recompensed?  I don't wish for rewards or wish for punishment or anything for anyone, but to feel as though he acknowledges that he's being heedless with others, then just simply asks for forgiveness, or basically to think he's 'gotten away' with what he did because Allah is so merciful and forgiving, sort of hurts.

What he did was beyond forbidden.  Alhamdulillah, whatever Allah decrees is best and we don't know how He handles things, and I've forgiven him and all, but it still hurts, basically my question is a general one:

**Question**: How should one react to being wronged by someone that is heedless and takes advantage of Allah's mercy?

Answer (score 1):

The Sunnah of the Prophet PBUH is clear on this. Refer to the countless incidents against the Prophet PBUH in Mecca, or even in Medina when Aisha RA was being slandered, etc. It is to forgive and move on.

This attitude of they’re “taking advantage of Allah’s mercy” sounds quite arrogant. Don’t we all take advantage of His mercy? Don’t we all wish for His mercy to be easy to get through Tawba?

If you don’t want to forgive, then it’s halal for you to take legal suit against the person, or any other halal option in redressing the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you have not forgiven him, your nafs (ego) is holding you back; forgiveness must be followed by forgetting too.  As a Muslim, you can either forgive or demand for compensation as the law laid by Allah swt, but Allah says forgiveness is best.

But you can not go around scandalizing, because unintentionally you will be harming and hurting and destroying the lives of those who had nothing to do with the one who has wronged you, for instance like his spouse or children a completely innocent party, which will make you a greater sinner.

You will need to call upon trustworthy true mumin to be the witness for your compensation, even if it is death penalty.